# Can I restrict VNC connections by SSH key or login ID?

Tags: ssh, vnc, restrictions

I want to offer friends access to the X desktop on host "foo" for collaboration, but only at certain times; meanwhile, I want to access that desktop myself at any time.

I have set up SSH port forwarding to secure the VNC traffic, and I can provide friends with a login on "foo" so they can SSH in and connect to VNC, but I want their access to be supervised. Consequently, I'd like to set up something so the system allows VNC connections automatically if it's me ( as determined by my login ID or my SSH key ), but requires me to manually trigger something first if it's someone else ( and in fact each time the other party wants to connect to the VNC server ).

I'm using x11vnc as the server, maybe it has some support for this kind of access control, but I would prefer that the solution uses a generic method that could work with any server.

Comment: I don't think ssh or vnc has an option but some firewall would but not sure what.. looks like iptables can though I don't use iptables much  and haven't tried this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-for-restricting-access-by-time-of-day.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am thinking I might look into inetd/xinetd as well.